# Reading files using Contiki on MSP430F5438A

Tags: file-io, msp430, contiki

I want to read a file from my computer and display it on the board. But we are facing a problem while reading the file as the board is constantly resetting. (The Watchdog is off)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please post some code to give us an idea what your program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to upload a file:

If you want to read a file from your local drive only way to do it by uploading the file into coffee file system (cfs) first than read the file using cfs library such as cfs_open, cfs_seek, and cfs_read as a reference have a look into this link:
https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Coffee-filesystem-guide

Modify the program ".c" file you are working to initialize the base64 and coffee commands in the shell by adding:

shell_base64_init();

shell_coffee_init();

Compile and upload via the command:
               `make TARGET=platformuaresingnow example.upload`

to read/upload .txt file by modifying some bash code. To do so, add the following lines

`%.shell-upload: %.txt`

```
 ``(echo; sleep 4; echo "~K"; sleep 4;``

     ``echo "dec64 | write $*.txt | null"; sleep 4; \``

 ``../../tools/base64-encode < $<; sleep 4; ``

    `` echo ""; echo "~K"; echo "read $*.txt | size"; sleep 4) | make login``
```

Now you can upload any .txt file to the coffee filesystem of the currently connected mote node using the command:

make testfile.shell-upload

Hope that it 'll solve your problem.